# Анимация на css не корректно работает

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Суть вопроса вот в чем. Анимация нормально срабатывает при hover, но когда курсор убираю, происходит не плавный переход, а резкий. Не могу понять что не так. Нужен плавный переход при наведении и когда курсор убираешь с элемента. Спасибо!

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}


@keyframes work-view {
  0%   { top: 0; }
  100%  { top: calc(45% - 25px); }
}
@keyframes work-opacity {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100%  { opacity: 0.8; }
}
 .div1:hover {
    background: #fcdc21;
    animation: work-opacity 0.3s ease;
 }
.div1:hover:after {
    content: "+";
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #282828;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
    right: 0;
    top: calc(45% - 25px);
    z-index: 1;
    animation: work-view 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
    <div class="div1"></div>
```

Comment: [mcve] сделай и сниппетом добавь.

Comment: Ссылка на код: (https://jsfiddle.net/94cxmb2r/) При наведении курсора анимация срабатывает плавно 0,5s, когда убираешь курсор, срабатывает мгновенно.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам,  только не знаю как себя поведет в safari

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.div1:hover {
    background: #fcdc21;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
 }
.div1:hover:after {
    top: calc(45% - 25px);
    opacity: 1;
}
 .div1:after {
    content: "+";
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #282828;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
        <div class="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Кто подскажет что изменить, чтобы работал в safari?

Comment: вы calc уберите и сафари проглотит это ..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#ccc;
transition:1s background;
position:relative;
}
.div1:hover {
background:#fe4;
}
.div1:after {
content:'+';
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:50%;
opacity:0;
font-size:50px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transition:1s opacity, 1s top;
}
.div1:hover:after {
content: '+';
opacity:1;


top:50%;


}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

</div>
```